# Get an error message when trying IBM Visual Recongnition module

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

Got an error message when trying IBM Visual Recognition module (Lite). Everything went well till I created a project. When I click on "add to project" and choose IBM VR and then click on Test bouton located in General panel I went to a page that allows to add some pictures. **Adding any pictures raises an error !!**

[pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3bvN.png)

An error occurred:

Something went wrong retrieving your Watson Visual Recognition service instance. check your instance for more details.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, IBM deprecated the **Watson Visual Recognition (VR)** service. See [FAQs for Visual Recognition](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/visual-recognition?topic=visual-recognition-vr-use-faqs)

Comment: I'm sorry. I was trying to notify people who are still searching for answers to VR problems to stop that path. I thought this might be useful to know for them.